# SQL exclude a where clause if the variable is null or empty

Tags: postgresql, variables, null, where-clause

I have SQL (postgresql) expression like of these:

```
select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where
t1.name = nameVariable and t2.field = fieldVariable;
```

Would it be possible in case nameVariable is null or empty to not execute the "where
t1.name = nameVariable " at all?

**EDIT**
Also I need to precise that I am using JPA and hibernate so the query looks like this:

```
@Query(value = " select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where
    t1.name = :name and t2.field = :fieldName;", nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Test> getTest(@Param("name") String name, @Param("fieldName") String fieldName);
```

Comment: Yes. it is possible. BTW: your left join reduces to a plain join by referring to it in the where clause `t2.field = fieldVariable`

Comment: Could you tell me how I can achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE (t1.name = nameVariable OR nameVariable IS NULL)
AND (t2.field = fieldVariable OR t2.field IS NULL OR fieldVariable IS NULL)
   ;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Sorry I was not all clear in the question (check the EDIT). I have tried your suggestion doing this (left forget the second filed for now I m just trying with one) @Query(value = " select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where
    t1.name = :name OR :name IS NULL", nativeQuery=true) and it didn't work, an sql exception was thrown (the input parameter name was null)